# Relationship between ordinal and (semi) ordinal variable

Tags: inference, ordinal-data

I have the following problem. I have conducted a survey about how people have consumed media in a certain way. The scale of responses was 1=never to 9=always. Also I have recorded exam scores for a specific exam for each of the respondents. These scores however are on a scale from 1.0 to 5.0; 1.0 being the best and they can take on the incremental values in between the two boundaries (increments of 0.1; i.e. 1.1,1.2,...,4.9,5.0).

I am now exploring whether there is a relationship between the survey results and the scores.

I am not sure which method best to use to establish if there's a relationship between the two. From other questions on here, I have seen that Spearman correlation and a chi squared test might work, but I am a bit concerned about the scale of the scores and I am not 100% sure whether one would even consider this truly ordinal data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spearman correlation will work with variables that are *at least* ordinal.  That is, if you suspect your scores are really interval or quasi-continuous, there is no issue with using Spearman correlation for this kind of data.

Also, with an ordinal scale from 1 to 9, that's probably enough categories where respondents are treating it as interval in nature.  That is, they are probably treating it as numeric, understanding, for example, that a response of 4 is half-way between a response of 3 and of 5.  In this case, I would probably be okay with treating this variable as interval, and Pearson correlation, if other assumptions are met, would probably be okay.  If this item was rated as (*never*, *sometimes*, *often*, *always*), I would advise against this approach.